# Bash If NOT OR With TWO Commands

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, command, pipe

I want to check that whether two programs exist or not.

```
if ! [ type gedit ] || ! [ type vim ]; then
    echo "Installing programs"
    #code
fi
```

> #code needs to run when one of them is missing.

What is the true way of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ! type gedit vim &>/dev/null; then
    echo "Installing programs"
    #code
fi
```

The purpose of the test command, `[`, is to set an exit status depending on some condition, like a file's existence or the equality of two strings.  That is not needed here because `type`, by itself, sets a useful exit status.

Also, note that you can specify multiple names as arguments to `type`.  It returns a zero exit status only if all names are found.

The purpose of `&>/dev/null` os to send all of type's output, both stdout and stderr, to `/dev/null`.  If you actually wanted to see its output, then remove that redirection.

Comment: Note that the `&>` redirect is a bashism which will not be honored in all shells.  Indeed, bash's behavior is arguably not in compliance with the sh standard, and `cmd &> file` should be interpreted by running cmd asynchronously, followed by truncating file (as it is interpreted by dash).  To portably redirect, use `cmd > /dev/null 2>&1`